# Split string to get coordinates/points

Tags: java, string, split, point

I am using the following code to split `(<x-coordinate>,<y-coordinate>)`:

```
String startPointStr = InputPattern.parsePoint(args.get(0));

String[] startCoords = startPointStr.substring(1, startPointStr.length() - 1).split(",");
Point startPoint = new Point(Integer.parseInt(startCoords[0]), Integer.parseInt(startCoords[1]));
```

Now, I want to modify the code so it also works for `(<x-coordinate>,<y-coordinate>),(<x-coordinate>,<y-coordinate>)`.
At the end I need two Points with two values each.

How can this be done?

Comment: Q: How can this be done?  A: If a simple `myString.split(",")` doesn't work for you, then consider using a regex: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/. Note, too, regex "groups".  Do *NOT* bother with "substring()", if you can possibly avoid it.

Comment: Could run multiple splits. First pass would look for `),(` as the split point and remove the outside parentheses. Second pass would split using just `,` for the in between commas like your current setup.

Comment: Otherwise, just split using `,` alone and then remove the parentheses using the fact that even positions will have the parenthesis on the left and odd positions will have it on the right. Just gotta do a modulus on `i` as you loop through the splits to figure which is which.

Comment: @FoggyDay @TimHunter Shoulnd't something like this also work? `String[] endCoords = input.split("[(),]");`? There are two spaces in the middle though.

Comment: @DonaldDuck - No.  String.split() accepts a regex, and "[", "(", "]", etc. all happen to be regex metacharacters.  So it might not behave as you'd expect ;)  Tim Hunter gave a great example for using a (very clever!) regex.  Note, too, that each "find()" returns a regex "group".  Each element in "split()" is also a regex "group".  Q: You aren't related to [Ludwig von Drake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12873296/ludwig-von-drake), are you ;)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked around a bit more and a efficient solution would be like the code example found [here](https://devqa.io/extract-numbers-string-java-regular-expressions/) which will just ignore all values that are not a series of numbers.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("(100,200),(300,400)");

    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    while(m.find())
        values.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));

    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    if(values.size() % 2 == 0)
        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i += 2)
            points.add(new Point(values.get(i), values.get(i + 1)));

    for(Point point : points)
        System.out.println(point.x + ", " + point.y);
```

But the multiple splits solution will work well enough for your purposes if efficiency is not an issue you're worried about.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you need to check if the size of values is even?

Comment: @DonaldDuck In case the String doesn't have pairs of values. You'll get an out of bounds error if there's an odd number of values in the collection when it tries to grab the last pair since there won't be a Y value to grab for it.

Comment: Not strictly necessary if you can guarantee pairs at all times, but otherwise you wanna account for it in the case of a bad data set or something.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java >= 9 you can use the results() method on Matcher to get a stream of MatchResult and produce a List of Point objects:

```
    String input = "(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(500,600),(1000,2000)";
    Pattern cp = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?=,),(?<=,)\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = cp.matcher(input);
    List<Point> points = matcher.results()
                            .map(coordinate -> {
                                String xy = coordinate.group();
                                int x = Integer.parseInt(xy.split(",")[0]);
                                int y = Integer.parseInt(xy.split(",")[1]);
                                return new Point(x, y);
                            })
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("points: " + points);
```

Result:

> points: [java.awt.Point[x=1,y=2], java.awt.Point[x=3,y=4], java.awt.Point[x=5,y=6], java.awt.Point[x=500,y=600], java.awt.Point[x=1000,y=2000]]

The regex pattern gets the coordinates without the parentheses. Then in the map method the split method is used to get the x and y coordinates and produce the Point object.